# How to get number of rows in NSIndexPath section

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsindexpath

I want to get the number of rows in an NSIndexPath section. For all my searching here & in Apple's docs I can't find how to get this value. Any clues on it?

My specific purpose is to use that to determine whether or not the selected row is the last row in the section so if anyone has a suggestion for determining that by another means that would be as good.

Comment: Pleasantly surprised at the number of answers so quickly. Thanks to all :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's how I do it in my case:

The table section holds a list of objects stored in `NSArray`, hence the amount of rows in section is the amount of objects in the array. In your case - if row is not the object from array - just do the check

```
if ([indexPath row] + 1 == [_objectsArray count]) {
    ...
```

But if your items in table are not held in a collection, you can easily retrieve number of rows in section just by calling appropriate method on `tableView` object in your `didSelectRow..` delegate method:

```
NSInteger numberOfRows = [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:[indexPath section]];
```

Comment: I like that solution using the array count but shouldn't it be [indexPar row] == [_objectsArray count] - 1 ?

Answer (score 11):

Everything is in docs

[numberOfRowsInSection:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/numberOfRowsInSection:)

```
int rows = [table numberOfRowsInSection:indexPath.section];
```

Comment: I agree everything is in the docs but sometimes they can be a nightmare to find ;)

Comment: @Pedro hang in there. Once you learn the dialect and structure, they are a breeze to navigate (and highly searchable if you know naming conventions) :-)

Answer (score 6):

The only way is to ask the data source of the table:

```
NSUInteger rowCount = [tableView.dataSource tableView:tableView numberOfRowsInSection:indexPath.section];
```

Comment: False. It is not the only way. UITableView holds the appropriate method as well which is cached value of `dataSource`.

Comment: @Eimantas: Of course there's an infinite number of ways to retrieve the result. What I meant is that there's no way to get it from just the index path. Maybe I did not make this clear enough.

Comment: I would offer the word "canonical" in place of "only". Anything else is either, as @Eimantas suggests, a cache of this, or an ugly hack around it which is too-tightly coupled to the data model.

Answer (score 2):

You can call `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` method of the `UITableViewDataSource`, passing the section number. However, it is your own code that produces this number based on what's in the model, so it may make sense to look at the implementation of `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` in your data source to see if you could get the same answer through an alternative path.

Comment: Thanks, given in this case the IndexPath is that of a TableView this will work.

Comment: @Pedro You do not pass the `IndexPath` to the `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:`, only a section number. You can check how many sections there are by calling `numberOfSectionsInTableView:`, but again the answer is produced by your own code in the `UITableViewDataSource`, so you may want to take a look there.

Comment: Yes, I'm passing the section number as [indexPath section].

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about on a UITableView, you can ask it's dataSource, which is somewhat likely to be yourself :-)

```
[self.tableView.dataSource tableView: self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection: indexPath.section];

// or, if you are the dataSource...
[self tableView: self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection: indexPath.section];
```